# Obtaining the Unique Push ID in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push, unique

Scenario is : json object are uploaded from a rest api and to be accessed by an android app.

Isuue: at each upload, the object is stored under unique push id. This is variable and not known at receiver end. So complete path is not known.

In given part of code:

```
    mRootRef = new Firebase("https://solvewa2y.firebaseio.com");
    Firebase messagesRef=mRootRef.child(postId);
```

I need to replace postId with something so that I can get the object stored irrespective of the unique id OR a way to get the unique id each time

Comment: If the key is auto-generated on another client there is no magical way that the Android client can know it. So you will either need to listen at a higher level `e.g. mRootRef.addChildEvenListener()` or use predictable keys.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Members can post much more concise and relevant answers if you start by describing the use case, constraints, and approaches you've already ruled out, rather than just the proposed solution (magically sharing an id between two clients).

Answer (score 7):

The answer is really simple.  I struggled for a solution with eventlisteners until I found this answer [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html)

```
 //Create new reference        calling push creates the unique key in firebase database but has no data yet
 DatabaseReference mypostref = databaseRef.push();

 //Use the new reference to add the data
 mypostref.setValue(data);

 //Call getKey on the ref - you must have 'key' in your data class
 String mypostref.getKey());
```